# Element type is invalid : While importing tsx files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am getting below error while importing .tsx files.

> "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."

Everything works fine if I change .tsx to .js

I am using below versions :

typescript : 4.7.2

awesome-typescript-loader : 5.2.1

Below is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "declarationDir": "dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "es7", "es2017", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDirs": ["src"],
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  },
  "files": [
    "src/index.ts",
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "tests/**",
  ]
}
```

My Webpack config

```
var config = {
  type: 'react-component',
  npm: {
    esModules: true,
    umd: false
  },
  webpack: {
    config(config) {
      config.entry = {
        demo: ['./demo/src/index.js'],
      }
      config.resolve.extensions = ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
      config.module.rules.push({
        'test': /\.tsx?$/,
        'loader': 'awesome-typescript-loader',
      },{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
          "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
          {
            // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
            "loader": "sass-loader",
            "options": {
              "includePaths": ['src/styles', 'node_modules']
            }
          }
        ]
    })

      return config
    },
  },
}
```

My AppBar.tsx file:

```
import React from 'react'
const AppBar = () => {
  return <h1>AppBar Demo</h1>
}

AppBar.displayName = 'AppBar';

export { AppBar };
```

And I am importing it like

```
import { AppBar } from '../../src/components/AppBar'
```

Comment: Hello Rohan; did you export the webpack config?

Comment: @Ebay Yes. I have done that.

Answer (score 0):

Change you import statement to

```
import AppBar from '../../src/components/AppBar'
```

and it should work

EDIT:
Actually I believe the issue is that you are missing a return type on your functional component. Import FC from react and try again

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'
const AppBar: FC = () => {
  return <h1>AppBar Demo</h1>
}

AppBar.displayName = 'AppBar';

export { AppBar };
```

Comment: We are not exporting it as default. So this will not work.